# How to match file name with a space in it in .htaccessfile

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-410

I have a file in my server named "Project orgstr2.pdf". I have to throw 410 response code for it. To do this I wrote following rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule Project\s*orgstr2.pdf - [G,NC]
```

But the issue is that the regex is not matching the filename. Please help

Comment: What is the URL shown in browser?

Comment: Is the .htaccess file in the same directory as your `Project orgstr2.pdf` file?